# Connecting segmented region in image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I am working on segmenting hands from monocular images and I have already come up with a pretty descent segmentation. The only issues I am having are when people have rings on their finger. Then the hand is no longer a connected component and I get the hand and the finger component. The following image shows my segmented mask, where the ring finger is detached because of a ring.

[image: Hand and finger]

Is there any natural method to connect components like these together? Otherwise I could try to segment the rings, but not all people have rings, so I would prefer to try to tackle this in this way.

Also, if there is another SE better suited for this question, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you can try to get the main axis of the hand, e.g. by looking at the igenvectors of the covariance matrix and then prolungate the finger in such a direction

Comment: @LJSilver thanks for the response! That is essentially what I was thinking, just doing it with the finger instead of the hand. I.e. getting the orientation and finding the vector that points to the hand. I am just uncertain of how to prolong the finger. I was considering to make a copy of the finger and translating it towards the hand in the correct direction. I think that will work, I'll report if that does the trick.

Comment: Yes that's smarter! However Im not in image processing so wait for some expert to answer

Comment: Ps. You can just slide the terminal part of the finger, that won't modify the rest

Comment: Why doesn't your method pick up the ring?

Comment: @geometrikal because the segmentation is based on thresholds from K-means, I.e. it is completely intensity based. There are several bright objects in the background, so shiny rings tend to be assigned to different classes. I also need to get spacing between the fingers, and to do that I subtract a thresholded gradient image, and that also affects regions where there are rings. I could use something like MRFs, but I would like the computation time to be less then 10 seconds per image and MRFs tend to be slower than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the missing area is due to a ring. A solution would be to use a PCA in order to compute the finger orientation. Then you apply a closing (mathematica morphology) with an segment oriented segment (same orientation as the finger).

It might modify a little bit the gap between the fingers where they are connected to the hand.